# Clarification on why I cannot override a method using a generic class parameter by a subtype of it

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance, overriding

Given the following situation ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xf47L0hPTs676tr2lyJEnQ))

```
trait Element
class Earth extends Element

trait Container[T]
class ContainerEarth extends Container[Earth]

trait Dummy[E <: Element] {

  def dummy(container: Container[E]): Any
}

class EarthDummy extends Dummy[Earth] {

  def dummy(container: ContainerEarth): Any = ??? // could not override
  override def dummy(container: Container[Earth]): Any = ???
}
```

It's still not clear in my head, why ContaineEarth could not override.

I have a solution to get around the business problem, but I need to understand why does the compiler refuse the substitution.

```
trait Dummy[E <: Element, C <: Container[E]] {

  def dummy(container: C): Any
}
```

I've been given that variance is in the game, and prevent it.

But for me, variance is about **Container[Dirt]** being a subtype of **Container[Earth]** if **Dirt** extends **Earth** when **Container** generic parameter is covariant.

So I'm open to all of your clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trait `Dummy[E <: Element]` describes a contract. A class implementing this trait must have method `dummy` accepting arbitrary `container: Container[E]`.

`DirtDummy` *is-a* `Dummy[Earth]`. So its method `dummy` must accept arbitrary `container: Container[Earth]`. If it accepted only `ContainerEarth` it would not be able to handle `container` that has type `Container[Earth]` but doesn't have type `ContainerEarth`:

```
class AnotherContainerEarth extends Container[Earth]

new DirtDummy().dummy(new AnotherContainerEarth)
```

So this would be a violation of the contract.

When you define `def dummy(container: ContainerEarth): Any` this is not overriding but overloading.

Comment: I completly ommited the fact that preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype. And was only concern by the fact that ContainerEarth can substitute to Container[Earth]...